# PHP - $_SESSION - безопасно?

Tags: php, безопасность, сессия

к сожалению не смог найти ответ на данный вопрос.

Безопасны ли $_SESSION в PHP? А самый главный вопрос: **"Может ли провайдер прочесть/зайти под моей сессией?"**

Comment: сессии это обычный способ хранить данные на стороне сервера. Данные сессии не передаются между клиентом и сервером. так что провайдер клиента не может их прочесть. Данные сессии может прочесть тот, кто имеет доступ к серверу. Чтобы подхватить сессию нужна кука, хранящая идентификатор сессии. Если ее перехватить, то можно с ней и залогиниться.

Comment: @teran, спасибо за ответ! Значит, провайдер не сможет зайти под моей сессией на какой то сайт?

Comment: если он из траффика отфильтрует куки, то может с ними зайти. Если вы ходите на сайт по хттп**с** то это наверное, маловероятно (менее вероятно).